# V49. Lightning redirect to specific tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, tab, redirect

I'm creating a lightning component and need to redirect to custom tab after the user click on Accept button.

I'm using this code but not working and it's is not supported

```js
handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {

    var idx = "a055J000000wKxXQAU";
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
        "recordId": idx,
        "slideDevName": "detailTab"
    });
    navEvt.fire(); 
},
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation the attribute "slideDevName" should be "detail" which is also  the default value and not "detailTab" like this

```
 navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX",
      "slideDevName": "detail"
    });
```